# How do I test mdDialog w/o mock for the 2nd controller?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Intro: we use Jasmine and AngularJS.

The way we test `mddialog` is that we create a mock for it:

```
mockMdDialog = jasmine.createSpyObj('mdDialog', ['alert', 'confirm', 'show', 'hide']);
mockMdDialog.show.and.callFake(function() {returnq.when(true);});
```

And then for some reason we use a second `mdCnfrmDialog`:

```
mdCnfrmDialogMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('mdDialog',
            ['title', 'textContent', 'ariaLabel', 'ok', 'cancel']);
mdCnfrmDialogMock.title.and.returnValue(mdCnfrmDialogMock);
mockMdDialog.confirm.and.returnValue(mdCnfrmDialogMock);
```

Question #1: does it mean that essentially we mock the same object (`mdDialog`) but use different mock objects for different methods (`mockMdDialog` for `alert`, `confirm` etc, and mdCnfrmDialog for `title`, `textContent` etc?)

Question #2: how does the last line (`mockMdDialog.confirm.and.returnValue(mdCnfrmDialogMock);`) works? Is it true that we hardcode the `confirm` result by doing `when(true)` so we always set value to `mdCnfrmDialogMock`. How does it help us?

Question #3: can we actually avoid creating `mdCnfrmDialogMock` and create an actual fake dialog with a hardcoded `title` string value?

Thanks! I'm sorry for this newbie questions.